# firefox/IE designMode reference needed

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, designmode

I am looking for reference documentation for designMode in Firefox 2/3 and IE 6/7/8.  Does anyone have links to good references?

Answer (score 4):

> [Converting an app using document.designMode from IE to Mozilla.](http://www.mozilla.org/editor/ie2midas.html)
>
> http://starkravingfinkle.org/blog/2007/07/firefox-3-contenteditable/
>
> http://starkravingfinkle.org/blog/2007/02/xul-clippings-midas-rich-text-editor/

Answer (score 3):

Try [Mozilla's developer reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla). (Also indicates IE inconsistencies and omitted commands.)